# PHP Login & Sessions without Craft Commerce?

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/03/php-login-script.html) tutorial in my Craft CMS site, I've created all the files and they currently reside in public_html, but twig and the .htaccess of Craft CMS is interfering with it.

Does anyone know what the directory structure should look like to integrate this with craft cms or whether it's possible by other methods?

Appreciate any help.

My current directory goes like:

```
(C-Panel) Home
     -----template
     -----public_html
          ----php-login-script-level-1
          ----Craft .htaccess
          ----Craft index.php (pulling from template)
```

Is it possible to set this up without Craft interfering with it?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is still a pretty bad tutorial. They teach very poor programming habits and the code is sub-par quality.

Comment: ah, is there any better ones you know of? any that actually help you understand what's happening would be good, I'm assuming tho the way I'd get this one to work would be to move the php-login-script-level-1 folder into the home directory and then pull the contents from it with .htaccess in public_html?

Comment: Not a tutorial, but here on SO there is plenty of information about PHP and authentication systems. e.g. [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/1839439)

Comment: Thanks that's useful but I still need to know how to implement that with craft, the link in my question shows the directory of php-login-script-level-1 is there anything in there I'd need to have in a certain place to work with craft? I can't find anything on integrating a login system with a cms.